# NFL players with multiple punt return touchdowns in a game

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

[Nyheim hines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyheim_Hines) of the Indianapolis Colts returned 2 punts for touchdowns in the week 16 game of the 2019-20 season against the Carolina Panthers.

How many players have returned multiple punts for touchdown in the NFL history? Please list the athletes, and the games this was achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of players with multiple returned punt touchdowns in a game I've found so far (from 1990 till now). They've been listed in reverse chronological order, and all of them have returned exactly two touchdowns in the specified games listed below:

- [Nyheim Hines](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/H/HineNy00/gamelog/2019/) of Indianapolis Colts in 2019 ([week 16](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201912220clt.htm) against the Carolina Panthers)
- [Darius Reynaud](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/R/ReynDa00/gamelog/2012/) of Tennessee Titans in 2012 ([week 17](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201212300oti.htm) against the Jacksonville Jaguars)
- [Reggie Bush](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/B/BushRe00/gamelog/2008/) of New Orleans Saints in 2009 ([week 5](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/200810060nor.htm) against the Minnesota Vikings)
- [Eddie Drummond](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/D/DrumEd00/gamelog/2004/) of Detroit Lions in 2004 ([week 10](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/200411140jax.htm) against the Jacksonville Jaguars)
- [Steve Smith](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/S/SmitSt01/gamelog/2002/) of Carolina Panthers in 2002 ([week 14](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/200212080car.htm) against the Cincinnati Bengals)
- [Jermaine Lewis](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/L/LewiJe00/gamelog/2000/) of Baltimore Ravens in 2000 ([week 17](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/200012240rav.htm) against he New York Jets)
- [Jermaine Lewis](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/L/LewiJe00/gamelog/1997/) of Baltimore in 1997 ([week 15](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/199712070rav.htm) against the Seattle Seahawks)
- [Darrien Gordon](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/G/GordDa20/gamelog/1997/) of Denver Broncons in 1997 ([week 11](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/199711090den.htm) against the Carolina Panthers)
- [Eric Metcalf](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/M/MetcEr00/gamelog/1997/) of San Diego Chargers in 1997 ([week 10](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/199711020cin.htm) against the Cincinnati Bengals)
- [Eric Metcalf](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/M/MetcEr00/gamelog/1993/) of Cleveland Browns in 1993 ([week 8](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/199310240cle.htm) against the Pittsburgh Steelers)
- [Todd Kinchen](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/K/KincTo00/gamelog/1992/) of Los Angeles Rams in 1992 ([week 17](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/199212270ram.htm) against the Atlanta Falcons)

Answer (score -3):

Since 1994, this has happened 10 times (same player, same game, returned 2 punts for touchdown).

Why since 1994?  Because that is what is offered on Football Reference dot com.